# How to fetch a website progressive like the browser?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a website using `python` which needs request to google. When I open Google website in Chrome, then the browser opens this site progressive. I mean in the browser, half of loading time is for `ttfb` and the other half is for `download` like this:

[image]

I am fetching Google using the `requests` library. In `requests` there is a flag `stream` which is used to download or upload files progressively. If I set `stream` to true, then I get the response line by line. But `requests` gives all of lines in the same time, which means all of fetching time is for `ttfb` not `download` like this:

[image]

Also if I set `stream` to false, time of getting response does not change much like this:

[image]

So, how can I fetch Google like Chrome progressively?

Comment: First you need to pull the html text - which you're doing with `requests.get` - parse it, and look for scripts, img, and link elements (maybe a couple others). Then queue up requests for those elements' src attributes. You do this several at a time using threads and waiting for them all (or not, depends on you). You are now progressively gathering the files from the server.

Comment: @RichardBarker tanks for fast reply. you mean `download` part of loading page is for fetching `static-files`? if yes then why when i use browser to open google it takes 0.249 seconds but when i use `requests` it takes 1.953 seconds?

Comment: There are many reasons why that is the case. Without knowing a lot more though I can only guess. Extra overhead from python, python vs whatever language chrome uses, inefficient implemention in any part of your execution stack... The list is large.

Comment: @RichardBarker could you give me some reference?

Comment: That's what Google is for ;-) I commented my answer because I don't have code for it which is what most people come here for nowadays :-\ I'd start by looking for some benchmark tests done by others on your python libraries. Then if nothing comes up, consider use another way to get the files, curl maybe?